# ES6 modules: imported constants are undefined at first; they become available later

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use ES6 modules in my JavaScript application. The sources are compiled with webpack and babel. This is a shortened version of the file that causes me trouble:

```
export const JUST_FORM = 0;
export const AS_PAGE = 1;

console.log(AS_PAGE); // **

export default function doSomething(mode = AS_PAGE) {
  console.log(mode);
  console.log(JUST_FORM);
}
```

I use this functionality just as you would expect.

```
import doSomething, { AS_PAGE } from './doSomething'

console.log(AS_PAGE);

doSomething();
```

When I run the app, it prints three times `undefined` and only once the expected value `AS_PAGE` which is the `console.log` marked with `**`. However, this is printed last! It shows that:

- The `AS_PAGE` constant, when used as default parameter for the `doSomething` function`, is not defined at the moment of defining the function.
- The `JUST_FORM` constant is not defined when `doSomething` is called.
- The `AS_PAGE` constant is not defined when explicitly imported.

Apparently, what's happening here is that only the `default` export gets parsed and evaluated and the rest of the file is ignored until later. I import this file on several different places in my app (which is quite large at this moment) and at some point those values become actually available. Judging from the console output, it's matter of time, but it is possible that it has a different reason. Obviously, I do the importing exactly the same way in all places.

Anyway, I've written my whole application with the assumption that once I import something, it is immediately available and I can use it in my code. I read (briefly) about how ES6 modules should work and I haven't found anything that would prove this assumption wrong. And it has been working until now.

Also note, that the behavior is the same when I run it with `webpack-dev-server` or compile it to a single bundle.

Is this behavior really correct? What might be responsible for it?

Comment: Circular dependencies.

Comment: @Bergi I must be blind, where's the circular dependency?

Comment: @torazaburo: Not in the code he posted, but it's the thing responsible for this behaviour. I'll bet.

Comment: Thank you! It's obvious now. I think I actually considered it at one moment. The problem was that the cycle was very long and stemmed from an exceptional situation so I didn't think it was possible. I also didn't know that these are very clear symptoms of a cycle, otherwise I would have dug deeper. @Bergi, post it as a real answer please and I will accept it:)

Comment: @Bergi, do you happen to know if there is way to deal with the sometimes necessary circular dependencies in es6 import/exports?

Comment: @NikSo: Circular dependencies work fine in ES6 modules as long as you only export functions and do not reference the circular ones during the evaluation of the module (which includes `extends` clauses).

Comment: @Bergi I think this question is worth answering, since I'm sure many people will experience the same issue and try searching for the symptoms.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the answer here are **circular dependencies**.

There is actually no circular dependency present in the code provided in the question (because it's just a simplified snippet of code) but the symptoms are very clear.

The simplest example of a circular dependency is when file A imports file B and file B imports A. Unfortunately, what makes this issue hard to detect sometimes is that the circle can be arbitrarily large, spanning over a huge amount of files.

Circular dependencies are supported in ES6 and they can be used when one is careful enough. However, my takeaway here is that circular dependencies are very often a sign of bad design decisions. Which was exactly my case.

Comment: this was definitely the problem.  Did not realize `import { someThing } from "SomeIndex"` actually does the imports of everything in "SomeIndex", not just the one thing.  In this case, I was importing components from an index which contained the component I was working on.  Something like `SomeIndex exports { Button, ColoredButton}`  `ColoredButton imports { Button } from SomeIndex`.

Comment: This might be my problem, I just did a large refactor and now web-kit is showing this error... Unfortunately I have literally hundreds of changed files, and it's practically impossible to find out where this is originating by hand....

Comment: Same problem here @SephReed. Although I did know it imports the whole thing, but still did not realize I was doing it as I aimed at "just" my constants 

Comment: Google is really good, first result was the solution to my problem, I'm impressed...

Comment: I had 2 files, each file was importing a constant from the other file. Only having 1 file import the other fixed my constant being undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck for the last 30 minutes with a problem similar to this one, in fact in my modules i was exporting them like this:
module.exports = "something" instead of module.exports = {myVariable, myFunction}

took me a while to realise this one but i hope it can help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32529498)