# ES6 - import constant, but when used an Uncaught ReferenceError is thrown

Tags: javascript, constants, es6-modules, referenceerror

I have, as part of a js app, a file like this (with the names changed to protect the innocent):

```js
export const noValue = '';

export default class ValueProcessor {
    ...
    getValue(valueId) {
    }
    ...
}
```

And another file that imports those:

```js
import ValueProcessor, { noValue } from '../processor/value-processor'

class ValueSource {
    ...
    handleValue(valueId) {
        const loadedVal = this.getValue(valueId)

        if (noValue === loadedVal) {
            // signal that there is no value
        }
    }
}
```

In the check that uses noValue a 'ReferenceError: noValue is not defined' is thrown.  I've used this in other projects and it works and it works in other places both for constants and functions.  I can't see any reason why it doesn't work here.  Are there any particular things I should look for?

I've seen [ES6 modules: imported constants are undefined at first; they become available later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515816/es6-modules-imported-constants-are-undefined-at-first-they-become-available-la) and it isn't that.  The value-processor.js file doesn't import anything, so I don't see anywhere for a circular reference to be introduced.  Also, the default export from value-processor.js works fine.

===UPDATE===

I haven't been able to find a way to put together a simple example.  For now I'm using a work-around of having a static getter in the class that is exported.  That getter returns the const that is refusing to export.

Comment: Your first file has a syntax error. It should be `export default class ValueProcessor`

Comment: Can you make a [mcve], please? What environment does this run in? Do you use native modules or a (possibly broken) transpiler/bundler?

Comment: The syntax error is a typo, otherwise nothing would work.

I'm working to get a minimal example together.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `export default class ValueProcessor`. If thats a `ValueProcessor` class. Unless make ValueProcessor a const and then export it.
Here's an example working copy https://codesandbox.io/s/370607wlm.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem - the missing 'class' was just a typo.  I'm trying to get a small example that's broken.  Unfortunately a simple app doesn't demonstrate the problem.  There's definitely some issue hidden somewhere because some imports work and others don't.

Comment: I am still not clear whats your question. May an example would help.

Comment: My question is what, other than circular references, which can't happen in this case because the file containing the exported constant doesn't import anything, can cause this problem?

I did say I'm trying to get a small example that's broken.  Unfortunately that's not simple to do as your example demonstrates.

Comment: unless the file ref is wrong, it should work great. You can check here https://codesandbox.io/s/370607wlm

Comment: I agree that it should work.  The problem is that it doesn't.  I already looked at that link and that doesn't resolve the problem because that's already what the code looks like.  It's not the file ref because the default export from the file works fine, only the constant I'm trying to import from the file doesn't work.  And the constant does have an export on it.  Exports of constants from other files do work and there's no difference in their definition - export const ...