# ES6 modules - imported constants undefined if not in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, undefined, es6-modules

The only similar question I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515816/es6-modules-imported-constants-are-undefined-at-first-they-become-available-la) but I can't see how would I have caused a circular dependancy in this case:

I have a file exporting **constants** like so:

(choices array version is for using in Select inputs and the other one secures from typing errors in condition checks)

**payments.constants.js**

```
export const paymentMethodChoices = [
    { id: "Cash", name: "Cash" },
    { id: "BankTransfer", name: "BankTransfer" },
];

export const paymentMethods = {
    Cash: paymentMethodChoices[0],
    BankTransfer: paymentMethodChoices[1],
}
```

When they are imported inside any of my `react` components all works as expected.

**MyReactComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { paymentMethods } from '../../../constants';

const defaultValues = () => {    
    console.log("const object is available", paymentMethods)
    
    return {
        paymentMethod: paymentMethods.Cash.id,
        /* ... other scalar values*/
    }
};

const MyReactComponent = (props) => { ... }
```

But when I try to import the constants in another js file and merge them in another constants I got an error saying they are `undefined`:

**defaultValues.js**

```
import { paymentMethods } from '../../../../constants';

export const dailyCostCalendarDefaultValues = {    
    paymentMethod: paymentMethods.Cash.id,
    vatReturn: true,
};
```

ERROR message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Cash' of undefined`

[image]

Comment: There's no errors I can see in the code you've provided, assuming the path to constants is correct and it's the same constants file. Might need some more context

Comment: Thank you - Maybe I should have created a sandbox in the first place, I was sure I must have been missing something obvious. Will update the question with a sandbox soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end it was really a circular dependancy but a really complicated one because of a long chain of files imports. Something like:

```
- external.js - file where the parent.js is imported    
|
 ... - parent.js - deeply nested parent file importing fileWithProblem.js
    |
     -- fileWithProblem.js - importing external.js
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the `export const () => {}` is not working.

I have fixed by changing them like `export function () {}` format.

After that it is working correctly but I can't understand why so.